# Convert 24 hr format to 12 hr AM/PM format in SQL query

Tags: sql, ms-query

I know there are several questions similar to mine, but I need specifics. Using SQL in Microsoft Query, I have a time column that produces a result like `1900-01-01 13:30:00:0000000` and I need to convert it to produce only a `1:30PM` result.

Now, my column is `ODS_COURSE_SECTION_MTG.CSM_START_TIME` so I need to know, when I'm in "Edit Column" where and exactly what in the "Field" to type.

I have done

```
CONVERT(TIME, ODS_COURSE_SECTION_MTG.CSM_START_TIME)
```

but that only produces a `13:30:00:0000000` result.

Please help! Please tell me exactly how to edit that column to get the `1:30PM` result.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Is the data stored as a [TIME](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx) field? If so then this should work (full example so you can see what I mean):

```
DECLARE @t TIME
SET @t = GETDATE()
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, @t, 100)
```

So your code should be:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, ODS_COURSE_SECTION_MTG.CSM_START_TIME, 100)
```

Comment: I also keep this link bookmarked for quick reference... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx